# Can you Lint parts of a file in different languages?

Tags: eslint, static-analysis

**BLUF: Can you use a linter to lint different parts of the same file with different rules/languages?**

I have some HTML files that contains blocks of code in various different languages in the body. In order to test these and make sure they follow the correct style I want to be able to lint these sections of the file in their respective languages.

Is there a linter that can do this or is there any way to achieve this? If I simply lint with the other language the html in the file will just throw up errors.

I know that I could collate these samples, write their content in separate files and then lint them separately but I'd like to avoid having to create and update them during a linting cycle.

Currently using eslint.

Example:

```
<h1>A Title</h1>
<p>
  Some text that is nice normal html that can be linted the usual way.
</p>
<pre class='javascript>
  // this is some javascript that needs to be linted
  const foo = bar;
  function myFunction() {
    somethingThatMightNotPassLinting
  }
  ...
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom plugin such as `eslint-plugin-html` to lint js in HTML files. Modify the plugin to look for `<pre>` tags instead of `<script>` ones.

Comment: `eslint-plugin-html` only lints code within the script tags. I want to be able to lint code within the html body (maybe my question wasn't clear enough)

Comment: Oh I see, then in that case you have two options, modify that plugin to look for `<pre>` tags as well, or migrate the content to Markdown and use `eslint-plugin-markdown`. The first option should be pretty straight forward